# Determine if text is a field using VBA and Word

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I'm using a Find/Execute routine to find some text. If that text is a field, I want to turn it into static text. As Word finds the text, how can I interrogate it using VBA to find out if it is a field result? I'm not asking for the full Find/Execute routine; I'm only asking for the syntax to test if text is a field result instead of static text.

Comment: I was able to answer my own question, and I showed the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that some variation of the following will work:

```
If Selection.Information(wdInFieldResult) = True Then
   Selection.Range.Fields.Unlink
End If
```